# 75176B running very hot

Tags: rs485

I'm using this chip to drive DMX as is common. With no differential load/receiver load it gets hotter than is comfortable to touch, and with a receiver, still warm but not so hot.

The circuit is very similar to [DMX on Arduino with RS485](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100487/dmx-on-arduino-with-rs485/100488#100488) with no isolation and both enables pulled high to transmit.

The circuit is working as expected, but should the supply to the chip be current limited? 
Why so hot?

Schematic:
[a extract http://www.robocow.net/extract.png](http://www.robocow.net/extract.png)

Comment: Show a schematic of what you are actually doing, not something similar but with changes.

Comment: @OlinLathrop this is done, care to offer any answer?

Comment: I propose to close this question since the link to the schematic is not working.