# choosing the right Opto isolator?

Tags: arduino, rs485, component-selection, dmx512

In the process of developing an RDM Compatible DMX receiver board (using a ATMEGA328) and I have been fortunate enough to come across kimliv's most informative answer concerning such a board;

[DMX on Arduino with RS485](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100487/dmx-on-arduino-with-rs485/100488#100488)

However I was wondering why (if) it is necessary to use a TTL Compatible isolator? In this case the 6N317 or if perhaps a more traditional repeater isolator style circuit could be implemented using a more common and cheaper isolator for example the [H11A1](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1300/0900766b81300833.pdf) (which I just so happen to have in stock).

This all said it seems several DMX circuits I have come across utilise the 6N317 but so far as I am aware the transceiver ([MAX481](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1253/0900766b81253c33.pdf)) could be used to drive other isolators.

Is there something obvious I am missing here? or anything in particular that makes the 6N317 quite so desirable for its use here?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something obvious I am missing here? or anything in
>   particular that makes the 6N317 quite so desirable for its use here?

According to the data sheet for the 6N137 it can handle data rates up to 10Mbps: -

[image]

I took a quick look at the H11A1 and it has rise times and fall times of about 3 us. That informs me that it may be good for data rates of about 100kbps.

That's a big reason in my book for using the 6N137

Comment: i had considered this though disregarded it assuming that DMX was at low speeds, turns out DMX requires speeds of 250kbit/sec. thank you for pointing this out.